# Why does gyroscope drifts and is it possible to use position based calibration to calibrate it?

Tags: calibration, gyroscope

The MPU 6050 chips has gyroscope and accelermeter, and if you google anywhere they will tell you that the gyroscope drifts, usually at constant rate.

My question was, how does this drift come from? Was it because of the motion of the earth? If so, can we use position based calibration, like GPS coordinates to calibrate such misalignment instead of using a complementary filter?

Comment: How position calibration will help for gyro, which is *orientation* sensor?

Comment: *"If you google anywhere they will tell you that the gyroscope drifts, usually at constant rate."* Look again. Drift is not at a constant rate or it would drift to infinite. Furthermore, if it was actually a constant it would be super easy to correct for but it's not.

Comment: There is bias drift and scale factor drift. You do not specify which you refer to. Drift is due to temperature, imperfect manufacture, sensitivity to linear acceleration, and other thins as well, I'm sure.(vibration). I guess coriolis acceleration is in there too, but I don't see how GPS has anything to do with it.

Comment: @DKNguyen It is at constant if gyro at constant velocity.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate This is false. I already explained why.

Comment: @DKNguyen I experimentally tested it.

Comment: If you believe it is constant - calibrate it once and sell as a perfect gyro. You can make $millions on it.

Answer (score 1):

The bias and drift of the accelerometers and the gyros come about because they are not perfect devices. Initial manufacturing imperfections, drift with time and temperature, etc. It takes a pretty good gyro to even detect the earth's rotation, I doubt the cheap MEMS ones come anywhere close, but I have not done the calculations.

You can fuse IMU information and maybe a magnetometer heading sensor with GPS information using a Kalman filter to optimally correct for some of those errors.